# What is the difference between gem bootstrap-sass and gem twitter-bootstrap-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I am working to hopefully one day be able to build a rails app from memory.  I am following Hartl's book and today decided to experiment with a quickie from Rails casts because it looked simple to do.  They both involve the twitter boostrap.  Here's where I need help

**gem bootstrap-sass** worked fine per Hartl's tutorial
**gem twitter-bootstrap-rails** per the RailsCasts tutorial did not work as I have to install Python, etc.

So, as a complete noob to programming and web dev, I wanted to know what is the difference between the two if they are both reliant on the Twitter Bootstrap product?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

The first one is a translation of bootstrap less files to sass files. To integrate it you have to copy those files to your project. To update it you have to copy new version of those files again.

Second uses less and it is a gem that provides some additional functionality like generators. Integration is done through bundler and further updates also.

I prefer first solution. It's easier to keep control. It's also less magical so integration is simpler and less bug aware.

Here is a nice [comparison and explanation of available bootstrap solutions for rails](http://rubysource.com/twitter-bootstrap-less-and-sass-understanding-your-options-for-rails-3-1/).

Comment: That comparsion is a godsend, it took me a while to get my head around all the different methods of using bootstrap in rails. less,sass,pre-compiled,compiled.